# Camel:How to substitute output file path location dynamically?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi

Here is my Route:

```
<route id="comingFromSomewhere">
    <from uri="direct:comingFromSomewhere" ></from>
    <process ref="placeHolderProcessor" ></process>
    <to uri="file://{{property.FinalPath}}" /> 
</route>
```

Here is my processor:

```
public class PlaceHolderProcessor implements Processor {
 String gerantOutPutFilePath="C:/{clientName}/OUTPUT";
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String fileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName");
        String clientName= (trioptimaFileName.split("-"))[0].toUpperCase();
        String path = gerantOutPutFilePath.replace("{clientName}", clientName);
        exchange.setProperty("FinalPath", path);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to change my output path dynamically based on input file name. It's not working for me.Seems like issue is at '`<to uri="file://{{property.FinalPath}}" />` ' Can anyone please help me to fix ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Camel's [dynamic message endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo) like this:

```
<toD uri="file://${property.FinalPath}/" />
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. Since I'm setting 'FinalPath' like exchange.setProperty("FinalPath", path); So it's expecting in different way

Comment: Ohh, I made a mistake in my answer, I've updated it!

Comment: After applying '<toD uri="file://${property.FinalPath}/" />' to my code. I got another exception. Here is it: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 679 in XML document from URL [bundle://257.0:0/META-INF/spring/beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'toD'.

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Apache camel version 2.11.3. Is this version problem ?

Comment: Yep, the `toD` is supported from version 2.16!